# JQuery Reload to

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JQuery and Javascript, and can't find a good example online of how to refresh just the html object inside a div.

The html object is this graph from cosm.com
[image]

*index.html*

```
<div id="graph" >
<object type="text/html" style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:1%;"data="https://api.cosm.com/v2/feeds/120687/datastreams/sensor_reading.png?width=740&height=150&colour=%230055ff&duration=5minutes&legend=Vibrations%20measure%20%200%20-%3E%201024&title=Foosball%20Vibrations%20-%205%20Minutes&stroke_size=4&show_axis_labels=true&detailed_grid=true&scale=manual&max=75&timezone=Mountain%20Time%20(US%20%26%20Canada)" >
</object>
</div>
```

*script.js*

```
$(document).ready( function() {
updateGraph;
setInterval (updateGraph, 2000);
}
function updateGraph() {
     //This line is not working!!!!
    $('#graph').reload();
    //$('#graph').load();

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/spuder/PNK4k/

Comment: There is no such function as `.reload()`. Have you tried changing the source URL (e.g., add "&_rand=12334234123") to force a reload? Also, why are you using `<object  type="text/html">` when the result is a PNG image?

Comment: Try `$('#graph object')attr.('data', url);` where `url` is the path to the appropriate resource. @user113215's cache-busting `_rand` may or may not be necessary but it's safer to apply it than not.

Comment: And that's a good point about it being a PNG. As far as I can tell, you should be able to work with an `<img>` tag rather than `<object>`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll change it to an img

Comment: ... in which case the jQuery to update the image should be `$('#graph img')attr.('src', url);` where `url` is the path to the PNG (again with cache-buster if necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out http://jsfiddle.net/Bvpft/16/

Tested in Chrome and FireFox. It refreshes and redownloads the image but not sure what it's supposed to be doing beyond that.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <div id="graph" >
        <object type="text/html" style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:1%;" data="">
        </object>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready( function()  {
    var graph = $('#graph'),
        uri = 'https://api.cosm.com/v2/feeds/120687/datastreams/sensor_reading.png?',
        params = {
            width: 740,
            height: 150,
            colour: '#0055ff',
            duration: '5minutes',
            legend: 'Vibration measure 0 -> 1024 ',
            title: 'Foosball Vibrations - 5 Minutes',
            show_axis_labels: 'true', 
            detailed_grid: 'true',
            scale: 'manual',
            max: 75,
            timezone: 'Mountain Time (US & Canada)'
        };
    var updateGraph = function() {
        var data = uri + $.param(params);
        graph.empty();
        graph.append($('<object/>')
                     .prop({'type': 'text/html', data: data})
                     .css({'width': '100%', 'height': '100%'}))
   };
   updateGraph();
   setInterval (updateGraph, 1000);
});
```

---

Edited - Changed to Image, made non-flickering, added no-caching (Tested in IE10, Chrome and FireFox): http://jsfiddle.net/JAYDb/4/

**HTML**

```
<div id="graph" ></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#graph {
    background-color:#C0C0C0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 200px ;
    min-width: 750px ;
    display: inline-block;
}
#graphObject{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready( function()  {
    var uri = 'https://api.cosm.com/v2/feeds/120687/datastreams/sensor_reading.png?',
        params = {
            width: 740,
            height: 150,
            colour: '#0055ff',
            duration: '5minutes',
            legend: 'Vibration measure 0 -> 1024 ',
            title: 'Foosball Vibrations - 5 Minutes',
            show_axis_labels: 'true', 
            detailed_grid: 'true',
            scale: 'manual',
            max: 75,
            timezone: 'Mountain Time (US & Canada)'
        };
    var data = uri + $.param(params),
        graph = $('#graph'),
        obGraph = $('<img/>').prop({'id': 'graphObject'});
    var updateGraph = function() {
        var date = new Date(),
        src = data + '&' + date.getTime();
        obGraph.prop('src', '');
        obGraph.prop('src', src);
   };
   graph.empty().append(obGraph);
   updateGraph();
   setInterval (updateGraph, 1000);
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much. Works great in safari too.

Answer (score 0):

A closing bracket is missing?

```
$(document).ready
(  function() 
    {
     updateGraph;
     setInterval (updateGraph, 2000);
    } 
); // missing
```

You're jsfiddle is not working, because no jQuery version was selected. I've made a working example:

```
$(document).ready( function()  {
    alert("OK");
   updateGraph();
   window.setInterval(updateGraph, 5000);
} );

function updateGraph() {
    //This line is not working!!!!
    alert("ok");
    //$('graph').reload(); // unknown method?
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mmGT9/4/

What do you mean with "$('graph').reload(); ? Is that a custom function?

If you want to reload the "object", I would remove the object from the HTML area and leave just the blank DIV. Then add the following line in your javascript function.

```
$("#graph").html('<object type="text/html" style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:1%; " data="https://api.cosm.com/v2/feeds/120687/datastreams/sensor_reading.png?width=740&height=150&colour=%230055ff&duration=5minutes&legend=Vibrations%20measure%20%200%20-%3E%201024&title=Foosball%20Vibrations%20-%205%20Minutes&stroke_size=4&show_axis_labels=true&detailed_grid=true&scale=manual&max=75&timezone=Mountain%20Time%20(US%20%26%20Canada)" ></object>');
```

This will set the object into the element with the id "graph". Existing content within the div will be overridden. The function is called every n seconds and replaces the object, which force a reload. You can do it more pretty by using a variable.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mmGT9/5/

Comment: You've missed to save your fiddle after adding jQuery.

Comment: this is not an answer to the problem

Answer (score 0):

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/DcGqh/)

This Works..

I changed your `object` to an `img` tag

```
<img id='obj' style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:1%; " src=...


$('document').ready( function() {
    var i;

        var src = $('#obj').prop('src'); 
    setInterval(function(){
        i++;
        $('#obj').prop('src',src+"&"+i);

    },5000);
});
```